# React: Why does map() iterate through all the elements on the same line instead of printing on different lines?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of names to which I add elements like this within a function:

```
const [names, setNames]  =useState([])
for (const file of allFiles){
    setNames([...names, String(file)])
}

return (
    {names && names.map((name) => (
        <p>{name}</p>
))}
)
```

What puzzles me is that what gets printed to the website is every file name, one after the other on the same line. So every new name replaces the last until we reach the last name, and the only name that appears is the last name. However, I'd like to display every name on a new line. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Because setting state is asynchronous and you keep spreading into an empty array. There's no need to set state until you have the complete list of names: `setNames(allFiles.map(f => String(f)))` *(untested, but you get the idea)*. *(Or just use it as the initial state; we don't know where `allFiles` comes from.)*

Comment: It's because you aren't using React correctly. You are re-assigning the state multiple times for each re-render, causing more re-renders. Aside from the inefficient aspect of this code, it doesn't follow any paradigms outlined in the ReactJS docs, so you can't expect it to work correctly.

Comment: @DaveNewton basically I'm iterating through a list of IDs and doing a query into a database, which returns a file name (above code is simplified). Do you mean that I should append all the names to another array, such as `let filesArray = []` , and at the end set state to this array?

Comment: @VirajShah The state won't be set until after the loop runs. Without knowing where `allFiles` comes from it's difficult to guess what's actually happening.

Comment: @Ruo It's impossible to know what you should do if you're doing something other than what's shown. If you have a collection of async calls the mechanism is completely different.

Comment: @DaveNewton The state is, in fact set, with each call to `setState` – ReactJS just halts rendering until the main thread is free.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think I was unfamiliar with how useState hooks work, but your comment made me realize what I was doing wrong. It works now, thanks!

Comment: @VirajShah State changes can be queued *(whether for same state variable or different)*, changes can be rolled up, etc. If state was changed immediately this would work: `setFoo('bar'); console.log(foo); // "bar"`.

Comment: You might find you don't even need state, seen as all you doing is putting what's in `allFiles` into `names`, it might just make more sense rendering directly from `allFiles`, this is likely what @DaveNewton is referring too when saying were `allFiles` comes from, if it's from `props` then state is pointless, if it's from `useEffect` then it might make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you're structuring your code, but you need to set the state `names` only once at the end after your loop / your logic with files using the `allFiles` array.

It's as simple as doing `setNames(allFiles)` for the state to represent all the files in an array.

Also if you need to execute some code whenever the state that represents the files changes, or whenever the page is initially loaded, I suggest you look into the `useEffect` hook.

Comment: The useMemo hook is better in sunch situations. useEffect is an escape hatch that should only be used to connect and disconnect from systems outside React e.g. the DOM API.

Comment: @PJaoko  `e.g. the DOM API.`  or something `async`, that would be a likely place `allFiles` comes from.

Comment: @Keith In the example above, we already have the data, so no need for an Effect. Just memoize the names array, and if it changes it will trigger a re-render and recalculation.  Also, unless it is a very simple app, it is better to use a dedicated library like React Query for data fetching instead of doing it within an Effect.

Comment: @PJaoko  In the example above, no point in using `useMemo` either.  And what effect do you think React Query uses for fetching data.. :)

Comment: @Keith The point of using a library that uses an Effect once, instead of you having Effects all over your components is to have clean, easily maintainable code. 


UseMemo is useful when the data from the server changes. If it does not change, we would not even have to fetch it. We'd just use a static json file.

Comment: @PJaoko  Not sure were this is going, using third party libs, well tested etc is great, but seems to be deviating from the point I was making.

Comment: Your point was that anything async should be wrapped in an Effect. My point is that use of Effects are discouraged: https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect

Comment: @PJaoko  No, that's not what I said.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in other answers you might want to look at something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const allFiles = ['fileone.jpg','filetwo.jpg','filethree.jpg']
  const [names, setNames] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setNames(allFiles.map((file) => String(file)))
  }, []);

  return (
    names.map((name) => (<p key={name}>{name}</p>))
  );
}
```

Comment: Might be worth pointing out in your example, both `useState` & `useEffect` would be pointless here, as you may as well just `allFiles.map(...)`

Comment: Agreed, but we don't know from the OP's problem what the data for allFiles looks like or where it comes from, I suspect if it were a flat static array, this question wouldn't have been asked.

Comment: Indeed, it's the reason Dave Newton in the comments was trying to clarify were `allFiles` was coming from, and without clarification we can't even assume it's not a static array, or a prop etc.. :(